# Upgrade to .Net-Core 3.1 causes authenticated controllers to 404

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently upgraded my project to .net-core 3.1  I noticed some bizarre behavior, all of my authenticated controllers 404.

I've left a default anonymous endpoint which I generally just use to verify that my api is working.
This controller is working just fine.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

This controller seems to work fine, despite not being decorated with the `[ApiController]`

I've found a [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/448) which state that this is related to the ApiVersioning

However I don't see a way to set that in the startup in .Net-Core 3.1

I've added `[ApiController]` to all of the authenticated controllers, the only affect I saw from this is that all of my Public Methods are now eligible to validations of the number of parameters allow to bind to the body. Everything still 404's

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //...
    HttpPost("ExternalLogin")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string entryCode = null, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

How can I get my controllers to receive the requests?

Comment: What version did you upgrade from? Can you show your Startup code.. the way that middleware is defined changed a bit in v3

Answer (score 3):

If you migrated from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1, you will have to adjust Startup class:

In ConfigureServices:
Replace `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);`

with

`services.AddControllers();`

And in the Configure method:
Instead of 
`app.UseMvc();`

Use:

```
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Comment: I'm using endpoints, but I didn't set the compatibilyVersion I'll investigate this later today, Thanks!